# Call functions of a class automatically in Python

Tags: python, class

This is my current class:

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.c= c
        self.b = b
        self.a = a

    def type_func(self):
        type = raw_input("enter the type")
        if type == "A":
            self.b = 5
        else:
            self.b = 1
    #cab().register()

    def input(self):
        self.c = int(raw_input("enter c"))
    #cab().display()

    def display(self):
      print self.a,self.b*self.c

c = cab()
```

I want to `call c.type_func()` and then make the program automatically call `input()` and when that is done, `call display()`.

How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the functions you want by simply adding self.

So to call input, you would call `self.input()` or for display call `self.display()`. The function will use the already instantiated object. Call this within the desired method of the class.